# Increase the number of characters in a captcha with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a code and I would like to modify it to expand the number of characters of the captcha to 5 characters or more (now it has 4 characters)

**this is my code js**

```
//Antes de enviar los datos del formulario debemos de validar el CAPTCHA
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", 
    function() 
    {
  document.getElementById("frmlogin").addEventListener('submit', revisarform); 
    });
    
    function revisarform(evento) 
    {
  evento.preventDefault();
//Si el CAPTCHA es el mismo de la imagen entonces enviará los datos al login.php
  if(validarrecaptcha()===true) 
        {
              this.submit();
        }
        else //Caso contrario limpiará el formulario
        {
         document.getElementById("frmlogin").reset();
        }
}
//Creación del CAPTCHA
    var codvai1='';
    function crearrecaptcha() 
    {
        codvai1='';
        var cantidadtexto=4;
        var vericodigovai=document.getElementById("vericodigovai");
        vericodigovai.value='';
        var letrasynumeros=new Array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'A','B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z');
        for(var i=0;i<cantidadtexto;i++) 
        {
            var x=Math.floor(Math.random()*34);
            codvai1+=letrasynumeros[x];
        }
        if(codvai1.length!=cantidadtexto) {
            crearrecaptcha();
        }
        vericodigovai.innerHTML=codvai1;
    }
//Validación del CAPTCHA
    function validarrecaptcha() 
    {
        var codingresado=document.getElementById("txtrecaptcha").value.toUpperCase();
    if(codingresado!=codvai1)
        {
            alert("reCAPTCHA Incorrecto, intenta de nuevo");
            crearrecaptcha();
            document.getElementById("txtusuario").focus();
            return false;
        }else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I tried to modify the code but I could not get anything, I also saw some tutorials to see if I could modify it but nothing

Comment: What happens when you set **cantidadtexto=5;** instead of **cantidadtexto=4;**?

Comment: Change the number of characters

Comment: I had done the same thing before but it hadn't worked

Comment: When updating that variable, what happens? Is there an error?

Comment: I have 2 codes, the test and the original, but nose because when I try to change that variable in the general code nothing changes, and in the test code if I change it, I do not understand